# Alterar paginas padrão criadas por MVC no Visual Studio C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, mvc

Quando crio o controller e uso *MVC 5 Controller with views*, using Entity Framework, as paginas de *Index, Create, Edit, Delete e Details* são criadas automaticamente com uma configuração padrão, e tenho que incluir uma class nova para alterar o *css* dos botões.

Gostaria de saber se existe alguma forma para que estas paginas sempre utilizem um modo personalizado.

Comment: Esse link vai te ajudar: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/4fcb5a/step-by-step-implementing-t4-custom-templates-in-mvc5-projec/

Comment: Perfeito, era exatamente isto que eu procurava. Obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Gostaria de saber se existe alguma forma para que estas paginas sempre
>   utilizem um modo personalizado.

Sim, existe. Você pode usar para isso o `T4 Templates` do Visual Studio para personalizar a geração automática das `Views` de um projeto específico.

O caminho com esses *templates* podem mudar de acordo com a versão do Visual Studio:

**{VS_PATH}\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web\Mvc\Scaffolding\Templates**

[Leia esse conteúdo](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/4fcb5a/step-by-step-implementing-t4-custom-templates-in-mvc5-projec/) para um passo-a-passo detalhado de como personalizar os templates para um projeto MVC5.

Segue abaixo um resumo dos passos:

1. Criar um pasta no seu projeto com o nome 'CodeTemplate' e copie para ela todo conteúdo da pasta Templates passada acima.
2. Efetue o Build da solution.
3. Localize no conteúdo copiado (arquivos cs.t4) os trechos que deseja personalizar. Obs.: os nomes das pastas indicam a geração que está sendo alterada